# bpy display shader node group value input as a slider

Tags: python, node-editor

I am creating a node group using bpy, but I haven't been able to find a way to display a float as a slider, like in this image:

[image]

```
import bpy
def group_input_slider_example():
    y_pos=-40
    x_pos=-220
    group_name='Input example'

    group = bpy.data.node_groups.get(group_name)
    if group is None:
        group=bpy.data.node_groups.new(group_name,'ShaderNodeTree')

    nodes=group.nodes
    #Group inputs
    group_inputs = nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    group_inputs.location=(0,x_pos)

    slider=group.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat','Slider?')
    slider.default_value=1.0
    slider.min_value=0
    slider.max_value=1.0

    #Add group node to active material
    nodes=bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.get(group_name)
    node=nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')
    node.name=group_name
    node.width=180
    node.location.y+=220


group_input_slider_example()
```

Comment: Hello, could you add asnippet of your code so we have a base to iterate from ?

Comment: Added @Gorgious